# Why Magento 1.8 better than older version?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.6, magento-1.8

I have one question related to Magento new version its good for security point of view and other points which are mentioned in the release notes but there is no much enhancement related to front end performance.

Currently I have Magento 1.4.2 on my ongoing project for which client complain me performance are slow for end user perspective, to overcome this issue I tried to test Magento 1.8 performance for similar test cases but I don't even find any performance boosting result like in category page I get same loading time in both Magento 1.4 and Magento 1.8 and also when I import 10,000 product and then check performance for loading time but there is no effect.

Can any one highlight why Magento 1.8 is better than Magento 1.4? It's obvious the newer version is better than old but I want to convince my client with some convincing point.

Comment: if your intend is only to increase the speed of site, you could use caching extension for it. Varnish+cloudflare combination surely will improve your site's speed

Comment: thats mean for performance point there is no different between in Magento 1.8 and Magento 1.4

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes#11310-changes I didn't using ver 1.8. But It may have some extra features for caching and reindexing concept. But it only won't uplift you suddenly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Performance refers to loading speed of magento website. To make faster loading , You can follow [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140327173649/http://www.gxjansen.com/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/)
There are no any updates with magento 1.8 related to performance. In this version 
mangeto team focused only on

```
a) Functional improvment -shopping cart, checkout, content management system, and product import and export.
b) Tax calculation - Value Added Tax (VAT) and Fixed Product Tax (FPT) calculations for the Magento admin, invoices, and credit memos.
c) Security
```